# Top 5 names where sum for last N days

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get result for below requirement.

I need to pull the data where top 5 row with highest sum for each day where sum range is last 20 days.

Database :

```
Name    Date       Value 
Sam     1/29/2021   5
Sam     1/28/2021   4  
Sam     1/26/2021   7  
Sam     1/25/2021   8  
Jack    1/29/2021   5  
Jack    1/28/2021   6  
Jack    1/27/2021   7  
Jack    1/28/2021   5
```

Result that I'm expecting is :

```
Date       Name    Value (sum)
1/29/2021  Sam     150  (top 1st sum from date range (1/29/2021)-20)
1/29/2021  Jack    125  (top 2nd sum from date range (1/29/2021)-20)
1/29/2021  Lu      100  (top 3rd sum from date range (1/29/2021)-20)
1/28/2021  Steve   150  (top 1st sum from date range (1/28/2021)-20)
1/28/2021  Tod     125  (top 2nd sum from date range (1/28/2021)-20)
1/28/2021  Jack    100  (top 3rd sum from date range (1/28/2021)-20)
```

One more point is even if Sam(name) is not exists in 1/29/2021 even though  in 1/29/2021 its row for (sum from date range 1/29/2021)-20) should appear.

Comment: Easy to do in PostgreSQL. What database are you using?

Comment: In MSSQL database